# What does sqlcl_int_runme dropped do?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

While working on SQL developer today morning. I got a wierd output as "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. Alias sqlvl_int_runme dropped" . I'm not sure why this came. Can you please help me to understand when does the above message occur and what it will do usually?

I just ran select query to display user details And I was expecting the same

Comment: Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you executed a PL/SQL procedure, which is a block of code in the PL/SQL language.
The alias, sqlvl_int_runme, was used as a temporary label within the database for a specific task. Once that task was completed successfully, we no longer needed the alias, so it was removed to keep things organized and efficient. It's a common practice in database management to clean up temporary elements like aliases once they've served their purpose, ensuring that the database stays tidy and runs smoothly. So, dropping the alias was just part of maintaining the database's functionality and performance.